# Make geolocation call synchronously in javascript

Tags: javascript, geolocation

Im developing an app based on geolocation, so its mandatory to get the position in the first place, even before the execution of the rest of the app. So, how can I convert this module in a SYNCHRONOUS way????

```
 var geolocation = (function() {
 'use strict';

   var geoposition;

   var options = {
    maximumAge: 1000,
           timeout: 15000,
          enableHighAccuracy: false
};

function _onSuccess (position) {
    console.log('DEVICE POSITION');
    console.log('LAT: ' + position.coords.latitude + ' - LON: ' +  position.coords.longitude);
    geoposition = position
};

function _onError (error) {
    console.log(error)
};

function _getLocation () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        _onSuccess,
        _onError, 
        options
    );
}

return {
    location: _getLocation  
}

}());
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Geolocation *has* to remain asynchronous, but you can achieve what you want by passing in a callback to your module's main function and calling it each in the success and error functions, after they have completed their processing:

```
var geolocation = (function() {
 'use strict';

   var geoposition;
   var options = {
     maximumAge: 1000,
     timeout: 15000,
     enableHighAccuracy: false
   };

   function _onSuccess (callback, position) {
     console.log('DEVICE POSITION');
     console.log('LAT: ' + position.coords.latitude + ' - LON: ' +  position.coords.longitude);
     geoposition = position
     callback();
   };

   function _onError (callback, error) {
     console.log(error)
     callback();
   };

   function _getLocation (callback) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
       _onSuccess.bind(this, callback),
       _onError.bind(this, callback), 
       options
     );
   }

  return {
    location: _getLocation  
  }

}());

geolocation.location(function () {
  console.log('finished, loading app.');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/zYrHH/)

Comment: how would you explain the "has to remain asynchronous"? Why is that? I feel I understand it but I would not be able to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not try to make it synchronously. Just implement some kind of event system for geolocation getter. This way it work asynchronously but geolocation initializes your app or components which requires geolocation.

Here's a dead simple example of how this could work:

```
var callbacks = [];

var onGeolocationReady = function (callback) {
     callbacks.push(callback);
}

function _onSuccess (position) {
     // iterare through each callback and invoce them
}

// and making component
onGeolocationReady(function () {
    // some code here which requires geolocation
});
```

I hope this helps.